# Multiple If Statment in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to output a result base on the condition met, but am only outputting one result, I don't know why I am having the same result all the time. Here my code

```
const newDate = new Date()
const startDate= new Date("Feb 1, 2021");
const endDate= new Date("Dec 31, 2021");


const newDateOutPut =()=>{
   if(newDate < startDate){
     return <small  className="badge badge-warning">Not Active</small>
   }else if (newDate >= startDate && newDate <= endDate  ){
     return <small  className="badge badge-success"> Active</small>
   }else{
    return <small  className="badge badge-secondary"> Completed</small>
   }
 }


return(
<>
{newDateOutPut()}
</>
```

Am only getting "Active" as output, even when the newDate is less than startDate

Comment: Well today is greater than Feb 1, 2020. You also do not check the endDate so everything will end up in the else if when it is greater than the start.

Comment: Did you tried to `console.log()` the values of newDate and startDate?

Comment: You can't have `const newDate` storing a date and being a function at the same time. Side remark: two dates are either `<` or `>=`, there is no 3rd case.

Comment: Are you actually able to run this? because there are two `const` with same name (`newDate`)

Comment: the function name is a typo, please ignore it. you can make use of any name

Answer (score 0):

`newDate` is not smaller than `startDate`. `newDate` is constructed to the current date. We're now in 2021, and `startDate` is in 2020.

Comment: I have updated the question, it was a typo

Comment: It works in stackblitz, check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-npzcxj

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you would have only one output in this case @gabriel, this is how `if/else if/else` conditionals works, returning the first truthy.

If you would like to have multiple results displayed for the conditions which are `true` only, I would suggest you refactor your code into something like this:

```
const newDate = new Date()
const startDate= new Date("Feb 1, 2020");
const endDate= new Date("Dec 31, 2020");

const newDateOutPut = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {
                newDate < startDate ? <small  className="badge badge-warning">Not 
                Active</small> : <></>
            }
            {
                newDate >= startDate && newDate <= endDate ? <small  
                className="badge badge-success">Active</small> : <></>
            }
            {
                !(newDate < startDate) && !(newDate >= startDate && newDate <= 
                endDate) ? <small  className="badge badge-secondary"> 
                Completed</small> : <></>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

However, If this isn't your goal and you would like only one data display then you can refactor these conditions on the JSX function properly as it suits you.

Comment: I am still having the same output "active"